# A complex model query in django concerning related objects

Tags: python, django, django-models

Suppose I have the following two models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    type = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    type = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    a = models.ForeinKey(A)
```

I want such A instances:

1. Its name is 'name_a' and its type is 'type_a'
2. It has at least one B objects related to it whose name is 'name_b' and whose type is 'type_b'

Is there a way to get such A instances at one time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#filter) as follow:

```
A.objects.filter(name='name_a', type='type_a',
                 b__name='name_b', b__type='type_b').distinct()
```

**UPDATE** Added [`distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) to prevent duplicate objects.

Comment: Add `distinct()` to prevent duplicate objects.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry, Thank you for advice. I updated the answer to include that.